# Control click not working as second mouse button using VNC Viewer to linux running x11vnc

Tags: trackpad, remote-desktop

I'm on a Macbook running Vnc Viewer (6.21.406) connected to x11vnc (0.9.13) running on my work Linux box (redhat 7.9 Maipo) over a ssh link.  Everything works fine except that I typically use control-click on my Macbook to do a right click.  This works in Chrome, Eclipse, Messages, etc..  For some reason this key/button combination not longer gets correctly remoted to the Linux box.  Eclipse, p4v, Chome, etc. doesn't understand it.

This used to work but I'm wondering if a system upgrade recently changed some settings or something.  I've run `xev` under linux and it shows the control and the click appropriately so maybe the linux applications don't know what control-click is?  Maybe something was mapping control-click to be right-click automagically before and is no longer?

Does this sound familiar to anyone?  Any ideas what I should try next to resolve this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ctrl click doesn't even work in a VM running Windows. It demands an actual right click.

Comment: Yeah thanks @Tetsujin.  I thought initially that the applications knew it natively but I'm wondering if something _used_ to magically map it to an actual right click.

Comment: Wow, after fighting with this for a couple of days, I just found the Vnc Viewer setting that resolves it.  Sigh.  I'll post my own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe something was mapping control-click to be right-click automagically before and is no longer?

I've been fighting with this for a couple of days but I just figured it out 10 minutes after posting this question.  I'm not sure when but I must have either upgraded VNC Viewer and it changed the default or its settings got whacked recently somehow.

Under VNC Viewer → Preferences → Expert there is a **Emulate2** setting that needs to be set to **True**.  The description of the setting says:

> Allow a VNC Viewer user to emulate a missing right mouse button by holding down the Ctrl key while clicking.

Here's the [description of the Emulate2 setting from the RealVnc page](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002254618-VNC-Viewer-Parameter-Reference-?utm_campaign=vnc-connect-sw&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=vncviewer-mac-6.21.406.44671#viewer-emulate2).

Hopefully this helps someone else.